# Дождаться выполнения асинхронной функции

Tags: typescript, асинхронность, promise

у меня есть метод класса для работы с БД который представляет из себя ожидание изменений в БД:

```
    /**
 * Отслеживает изменения в записях указанной таблицы базы данных.
 * @param table - Название таблицы, которую нужно отслеживать.
 * @param conditions - Условия для выборки записей в формате { поле: значение }.
 * @param timeStop - Максимальное время выполнения отслеживания в миллисекундах.
 * @param orderBy - Параметры сортировки записей в формате { column: string, direction: 'asc' | 'desc' }.
 * @param callback - Функция обратного вызова, которая будет вызвана при изменении записи.
 * @param columnsToTrack - Массив названий столбцов, которые нужно отслеживать (необязательный параметр).
 * @returns Промис, который разрешится после завершения отслеживания.
 */
  

async trackChanges(
    table: string,
    conditions: Record<string, any>,
    timeStop: number,
    callback: (currentRecord: Record<string, any>) => void,
    columnsToTrack?: string[],
    orderBy?: { column: string, direction?: 'asc' | 'desc' },
  ): Promise<void> {
    let initialRecord: Record<string, any> | null = null;
    let stopTracking: Promise<() => void>;
    let trackingStatus: 'changed' | 'timeout' | 'no_changes' = 'no_changes';
    let hasChanges = false; // Флаг для отслеживания изменений
  
    console.log(`Запущена функция отслеживания для таблицы ${table}`);
  
    const queryFunction = async () => {
      try {
        const newRecord = await this.getSingleRecord({
          table,
          conditions,
          orderBy,
          limit: 1,
        });
        return newRecord || {};
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching single record for table ${table}:`, error);
        throw error;
      }
    };
  
    stopTracking = new Promise<() => void>(async (resolveStop, rejectStop) => {
      const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          const newRecord = await queryFunction();
  
          if (!initialRecord) {
            initialRecord = newRecord;
            return;
          }
  
          const changedColumns: Record<string, any> = {};
  
          if (columnsToTrack) {
            // Если указаны столбцы для отслеживания, фильтруем изменения
            for (const column of columnsToTrack) {
              if (!isEqual(initialRecord[column], newRecord[column])) {
                changedColumns[column] = newRecord[column];
              }
            }
          } else {
            // Если не указаны столбцы для отслеживания, отслеживаем все столбцы
            for (const column in newRecord) {
              if (!isEqual(initialRecord[column], newRecord[column])) {
                changedColumns[column] = newRecord[column];
              }
            }
          }
  
          if (Object.keys(changedColumns).length > 0) {
            hasChanges = true; // Устанавливаем флаг изменений в true
            trackingStatus = 'changed';
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            console.log(`Функция отслеживания для таблицы ${table} завершена`);
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            resolveStop(() => {
              clearInterval(intervalId);
              initialRecord = null;
            });
            callback(newRecord);
          } else {
            console.log(`Значение в таблице ${table} не изменилось. Повторная проверка через интервал времени`);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error checking changes for table ${table}:`, error);
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          rejectStop(error);
        }
      }, 5000); // Интервал 5 секунд
  
      const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
        if (trackingStatus !== 'changed') {
          trackingStatus = 'timeout';
          console.log(`Время выполнения для таблицы ${table} истекло. Функция отслеживания завершена`);
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          resolveStop(() => {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            initialRecord = null;
          });
  
          if (!hasChanges) {
            // Если изменений не было, вызываем колбэк с пустой записью
            callback({});
          }
        }
      }, timeStop);
    });
  
    stopTracking.catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Error while stopping tracking for table ${table}:`, error);
    }).finally(() => {
      this.destroy();
      this.initialize(this.type); 
    });
  }
```

вот как я пытаюсь его вызвать

```
 test('Проверка базового запуска', async ({page}) => {

        const trackChangesPromise = connectionDb.trackChanges("AR_RC_VALUE", { ISN_RC: resultRc.id }, 40000, async (currentRecord) => {
                 console.log('значение поменялось:', currentRecord); return currentRecord}, ['column_first', 'column_second']); //начать отслеживать

        //действия которые выполняются в то время пока ожидание начато
        await trackChangesPromise; //дождется возвращения функции
       // далее выполняется тест
    })
```

но код не дожидается выполнения функции и выполняется дальше от и возникают вопросы: 1) в верном направлении я мыслю? 2) что делаю не так?
заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Ну как минимум что такое `trackChanges` и при чём тут playwright?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что код не дожидается ответа? Как приведенный метод `stopTracking` используется в примере? Сейчас похоже, есть 2 абсолютно не связанных между собой куска кода

Comment: @andreymal Прошу прощения - поправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

внутри trackChanges не ожидается ни один из созданных `Promise`, поэтому она возвращает сразу решенный Promise.

Для решения нужно либо добавить `await`, либо вернуть Promise который нужно дождаться.

В данном случае

```
return stopTracking.catch((error) => {
  console.error(`Error while stopping tracking for table ${table}:`, error);
}).finally(() => {
  this.destroy();
  this.initialize(this.type); 
});
```